# "You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String" but it's a PHP

Tags: php, ajax, extjs, mvvm

Good day,

I'm pretty new in **extjs 5** and mvvm. I want to make an ajax request in order to display a treepanel with datas caught with a php.

Here is my store

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.servicesStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    // alias: 'store.servicesStore',
    storeId : 'servicesStore',
    model   : 'MyApp.model.servicesModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'app/store/data/GetServices.php'
    },
    root: {
        text: 'Events',
        id: 'root'
    },
    autoLoad: true,
    folderSort: true
});
```

I've seen that a "success" can resolve that issue but I don't need a succes as it's only displayed in a treePanel

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.tabServices.servicesTab', {    
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    xtype: 'servicesTab',
    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },
    useArrows: true,
    rootVisible: false,
     store: {type: 'servicesStore'},
    forceFit: true,
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'treecolumn',
        dataIndex: 'text',
        width: 600
    }, {
        dataIndex: 'mbt',
        cls: 'mbtcss',
        width: 80
    }, {
        dataIndex: 'bt',
        cls: 'btcss',
        width: 75
    }, {
        dataIndex: 'details', // port separated from rest
        width: 60
    }, {
        dataIndex: 'code',
        width: 80
    }]
});
```

So, when I launch my app, the "You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String" appears, how can I do to make it understand that I actually use a php file?
More precisely, that code is working in extjs 3.4

Comment: Does the PHP script call `json_decode()`?

Comment: @Barmar no, i use json_encode(). To make it clearest, I'm jsut migrating my application from extjs 3.4 to extjs 5.0, so that's working in extjs 3.4, I'm gonna precise that in my question

Comment: I guess that the answer works for you, but it would have been easier had you posted the data your PHP generates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the PHP code which did work under ExtJS 4 you must either modify your PHP to return the data in JSON format. Or otherwise you set your "enable compatibility" to version 4.

See "Enabling Compatibility" under http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/whats_new/5.0/extjs_upgrade_guide.html#Enabling_Compatibility.

```
compatibility: {
    ext: '4.2'
}
```